# Chown permission denied on samba share

Tags: samba, permissions, share

I have a raspberry with samba and it shares a drive inside the network and allow to everyone to write, read etc

I have another raspberry which mount the samba shared drive and I would execute, from this second raspberry, a chown on a folder but I don't have the permission.

I am going to set owncloud on the second raspberry which has to allow a user to own a folder.

On both Raspberry there is the default pi user, sambaRaspi has the following configuration

My smb config:

```
[MyAwesomeShare]

comment = MyAwesomeShare
path = /mnt/HDD
writeable = yes
```

cloudRaspi (raspberry with owncloud) mounts the samba share

```
//IP/MyAwesomeShare /mnt/SAMBA_SHARED_HDD  cifs username=pi,password=MyPassword,uid=1000,gid=1000  0  0
```

cloudRaspi need to run chown on the samba share

Comment: You should really post your `smb.conf` file to make it clear what you're doing exactly. Hint: create the same user on both Raspberries, so you don't have to `chown` at all.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev what do you mean with "create the same user on both Raspberries" ?

Comment: Just curios what is the filesystem of the device mounted at /mnt/HDD? If I am not mistaken fs like vfat or exfat do not support elaborate access metadata. So no chmod and chown there. Files will belong to the user who mounted the device (or is set in fstab).

Comment: @Ghanima the filesystem is ext3

Comment: Very well, then this should not be part of the problem.

Comment: This could be of interest: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98707/how-do-i-mount-a-cifs-share-so-i-can-fully-control-the-mounted-volume-on-the-cli and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/mount-cifs-network-drive-write-permissions-and-chown?rq=1 and on a side thought: why samba and not `nfs`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to create a new user (with `adduser`) on the RPi running samba, to match the user which runs OwnCloud on the other RPi.

As such, there are at least two possible ways to get correct permissions:

1. Change ownership of `/mnt/HDD` to the right user on the samba server.
2. Let the right user to create a new folder on the samba share. This would require `/mnt/HDD` to have write permissions for users of the share. Any directory created by those users will be owned by them automatically.

Comment: what do you mean with "create a new user"? I tried to create the user on both Pi with the same name and it didn't worked, I also tried changing permission but without results

Answer (score 0):

Let's say,

- `raspiSamba` is the raspi on which a samba server is running
- `/mnt/HDD` is a directory on `raspiSamba`
- `userX` is a OS level user on `raspiSamba`
- `raspiCloud` is the raspi on which owncloud is running
- `/mnt/mycloud` is the mount point on `raspiCloud`
- `cloudUser` is a OS level user (and also owncloud user) on `raspiCloud`

For the first 2 steps, forget about `raspiCloud`, we are on `raspiSamba`.

**Step #1:** Be sure that Linux system permissions are OK for `userX` to read and write `/mnt/HDD`, because **system permissions have higher priority than Samba permissions**.

**Step #2:** Check your Samba permissions for `/mnt/HDD` and `userX`. It should be something like the following:

```
[MyAwesomeShare]
comment = MyAwesomeShare
path = /mnt/HDD
write list = userX
```

Now, forget about `raspiSamba` and focus on `raspiCloud`. We are on `raspiCloud`.

**Step #3:** Be sure that the OS level owner of `/mnt/mycloud` is `cloudUser`.

**Step #4:** (as root) Mount `raspiCloud:/mnt/HDD` onto `/mnt/mycloud` with the credentials of `userX`. We don't need to have a `userX` user on `raspiCloud`. We just need to know its credentials. Here is an example of mount command:

```
mount -t cifs //raspiSamba/MyAwesomeShare /mnt/mycloud -o user=userX,pass=XXXX
```

As the final picture,

- `/mnt/mycloud` is owned by `cloudUser` who is an owncloud user from the perspective of `raspiCloud`.
- `/mnt/mycloud` is mapped to `raspiCloud:/mnt/HDD` as `userX` from the perspective of `raspiSamba`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46963/discussion-between-vaha-and-user4789408).